# How to delete all relative records in MySQL InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

Well, my friend told me I should start using InnoDB for my database, so I tried for my first time. And I have a problem with deleting records/indexes/fields/tables. Whenever I try to delete a record, I have to go to ALL the relative records, delete those and then go back to delete my original record. And I can't delete indexes at all! Is there an easier way to do this (since when I'm gonna run in in PHP, it won't delete anything) or should I just jump back to MyISAM? Which of these is better in your opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like deleting stuff a lot, InnoDB might not be for you. InnoDB is much, much stricter than MyISAM. It's faster when doing queries (`SELECT`, `SHOW` etc), but slower when doing updates (`UPDATE`, `INSERT` etc).

InnoDB's CASCADE is magic, but be very carefull. It's also very slow (because the db engine itself will check **all** constraints). If you're delering records that cascade into other deletes that cascade into other updates that cascade into other deletes etc etc, you'll be waiting a long time.

If you're deleting **in dev** and are annoyed by InnoDB's constraints, you might find `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` very helpful:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
/* do all kinds of dangerous deletes, eg. delete everything in the db */
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Don't use it in the app itself, or be absolutely sure that you won't break any dependencies.

Comment: Yes, the DB design is pretty much finished but i'm in very early development stages with the app, and testing is quite difficult with Key checks, but I think I will take a different action instead of delete, because I want to keep some data that has foreign keys.

Answer (score 3):

If you want dependent records to be automatically deleted when you delete a record in the primary table, you need to specify [`ON DELETE CASCADE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) on your foreign keys.

As per the manual, your choice of constraint on foreign keys is among one of these:

> CASCADE: Delete or update the row from the parent table, and
>   automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table.
>   Both ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE are supported. Between
>   two tables, do not define several ON UPDATE CASCADE clauses that act
>   on the same column in the parent table or in the child table.
>
> Note Currently, cascaded foreign key actions do not activate triggers.
>
> SET NULL: Delete or update the row from the parent table, and set the
>   foreign key column or columns in the child table to NULL. Both ON
>   DELETE SET NULL and ON UPDATE SET NULL clauses are supported.
>
> If you specify a SET NULL action, make sure that you have not declared
>   the columns in the child table as NOT NULL.
>
> RESTRICT: Rejects the delete or update operation for the parent table.
>   Specifying RESTRICT (or NO ACTION) is the same as omitting the ON
>   DELETE or ON UPDATE clause.
>
> NO ACTION: A keyword from standard SQL. In MySQL, equivalent to
>   RESTRICT. InnoDB rejects the delete or update operation for the parent
>   table if there is a related foreign key value in the referenced table.
>   Some database systems have deferred checks, and NO ACTION is a
>   deferred check. In MySQL, foreign key constraints are checked
>   immediately, so NO ACTION is the same as RESTRICT.

The default, if you don't specify anything, is `NO ACTION` -- that's why your deletes are not doing anything right now.

Comment: `NO ACTION` and `RESTRICT` are the exact same thing, functionally, I think. I think MySQL agrees. `NO ACTION` would mean the constraint fails, so the update isn't possible. `RESTRICT` would do the same.

Comment: @Rudie: Sure it is, the very first sentence of the `NO ACTION` description says so.

Comment: My bad. Didn't see that. At least I remembered it right from way back.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how it should work.

It preserves so called data integrity. If you have a user and an address associated with it you should not be able to delete user unless you delete an address first - otherwise you are leaving stray data in your database.

Your application should take care of making sure all related data is deleted, if no use `ON DELETE CASCADE` to enforce it.

Generally `innoDB` is much better for preserving your data integrity so stick with it and do not go back to `myISAM` (there is also a matter of what each engine is best fore but unless you give us more details there is no point in dwelling on that).